# Delivering python program with database postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to give my python program which uses **postgresql** as database to another person without them having the fuzz of installing postgresql themselves.

Is there a way of doing that without switching to sqlite?

Comment: use docker or host your db on a server and update your app's database setting. Docker will require some setup.

Comment: How do other programs handle database usage. You cannot expect from a user to install mysql or postgresql, right?

Comment: what kind of application are we talking about here? Desktop/Web App? SQLite is what is used if the app is supposed to work offline.

Comment: desktop app. How does "normal" programs manage that problem for example written in c++?

Comment: SQLite is how they do it. The apps that use other databases (Postgres/MySQL/MS SQL e.t.c) provide support for initial setup of database with their application. Like a developer setting up database using remote access. (Teamviewer / anyDesk)